# Pthreads signals getting lost when used as IPC inLinux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, ipc

We are developing a simple application in Linux for Desktop computer. The scheme is very simple and as below:

1. A main process which deals with the external world interface (which gives some data periodically) and spawns and keeps track of child processes.
2. Various child processes which process this data and report back to main process from time to time.

The data coming in from external world interface is in the chunks of around 240 KBytes and 1 chunk comes in at the rate of roughly once per milliseconds. All the child processes use and work on the same data i.e. the complete chunk is sent to every child process when it arrives.

The number of child processes is not fixed, can vary from 4 to 20. The scheme adopted for inter process communication is as follows:

1. Shared memory capable of holding multiple data chunks is created by all the processes using common key and using shmget() and shmat() APIs. Main process writes to this shared memory and all the child processes read from this memory.
2. To inform the child processes that new data chunk have arrived I have used pthread_cond_broadcast() API. The conditional variable and the corresponding mutex used for this purpose reside in a small separate shared memory and are initialized to default attributes in the main process.

So whenever new data chunk arrives (roughly once per 1 ms) main process calls pthread_cond_broadcast() and the child processes which are waiting on pthread_cond_wait() read this data from the shared memory and process it. The problem I am facing is:

Depending on the processor load, sometimes the pthread signals are getting lost i.e. either delivered to only some or none of the waiting child processes. This severly affects the data processing as the data continuity is lost (and the child process is not even aware of it). Processing time of the child process is average 300 micro seconds and this application is running on a multicore processor.

To pin down the problem I even created a dummy application with 1 main process and several dummy child processes who does nothing but to wait on pthread_cond_wait(). From main process I called pthread_cond_broadcast every 1 ms and a count was incremented and printed, similarly every time a pthread signal was received in a child process another count was incremented and printed. When I ran this test program I found after some time the receiver's count began to lag the sender's count and the gap between their count went on increasing. Am I right in my understanding that this was due to some pthread signals not delivered? Are there any other fast plus secure IPC mechanisms.

I even tried the same thing using internet domain sockets using UDP datagrams in broadcast (only for the synchronization purpose while the data was still read from the shared memory). But here also I noticed as the number of child processes increased the synchronization signals were getting lost. Please give your thoughts and ideas.

Consider the test program as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define     SHM_KEY             3579
#define     NumOfChildProc      20

int Packets_Tx = 0, Packets_Rx = 0;

void ChildProc(void)
{
    /* Create the shared memory with same key as SHM_KEY
     * Declare the condition and mutex and assign them the shared memory   
       address */

     while(1)
     {
         pthread_mutex_lock(PTMutex);
         pthread_cond_wait(PTCond, PTMutex);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(PTMutex);

         printf("From CP [%d]: Packets Received = %d\n",getpid(), Packets_Rx++);
    }
}

 int main(void)
 {
    int     shmid, i;
    pid_t   l_pid;
    char*   SigBlock;

    pthread_condattr_t  condattr;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;
    pthread_cond_t*     PTCond;
    pthread_mutex_t*    PTMutex;

    shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, (sizeof(pthread_cond_t) + sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
    }

    SigBlock = (char *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(SigBlock == (char *) -1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
    }

    PTCond      = (pthread_cond_t*) SigBlock;
    PTMutex     = (pthread_mutex_t*)(SigBlock + sizeof(pthread_cond_t));

    pthread_condattr_init(&condattr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_cond_init(PTCond, &condattr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&condattr);

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(PTMutex, &mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexattr);

    for(i=0; i<NumOfChildProc; i++)
    {
         l_pid = fork();
         if(l_pid == 0)
              ChildProc();
    }
    sleep(1);

    while(1)
    {
        /* Send pthread broadcast and increment the packets count */
        printf("From Main Process : Packets Sent = %d\n", Packets_Tx++);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(PTCond);
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You haven't really asked a question that can be confidently answered.  I would guess, however, that the problem is that occasionally there is no process waiting on your condition variable when you call `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.  In that case, the call has no effect.  You can expect that to happen more frequently when the system is more heavily loaded and when each process does more work between signals, but you need to be prepared for it to happen occasionally even in trivial cases.

Comment: Supposing that it indeed is an issue of there sometimes being no waiting processes when a new chunk of data arrives, the problem is really that your overall design does not accommodate that eventuality, not that `pthread_cond_broadcast()` is unreliable.  I can't suggest an alternative because I don't understand your processing model.  It seems you want all available processes to be recruited to work on each new chunk of data, but why doesn't it matter how many that is (supposing it's at least 1)?  That's the main thing preventing you from having a classic producer / consumer model.

Comment: Are you sure you can use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` across process boundaries? My understanding is that it is for inter-_thread_ communication.

Comment: Hmmm... 240KB/msec == 240MB/sec... Presumably you have 10GB networking, then, or at least 3 1GB network interfaces running full tilt... That's a fairly large amount of data throughput...

Comment: @juhist: Condition variables can be used across process boundaries as long as they were created with the process-shared attribute set to `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.  See [`pthread_condattr_setpshared()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html).

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_cond_broadcast()` signals do not get "lost".  Every thread which is waiting in a `pthread_cond_wait()` call at the point where the broadcast is sent will be woken - your problem is almost certainly that every thread is *not* waiting in the `pthread_cond_wait()` call at the point where `pthead_cond_broadcast()` is called - some threads may still be processing that last lot of data when the broadcast is sent, in which case they will "miss" the broadcast.

A pthread conditional variable should always be paired with a suitable condition (or *predicate*) over shared state, and a thread should only call `pthread_cond_wait()` after checking the state of that predicate.

For example, in your case you might have a shared variable which is the block number of the latest chunk to have arrived.  In the main thread, it would increment this (while holding the mutex) before broadcasting the condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
latest_block++;
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

In the worker threads, each thread would keep track of the last block it has processed in a local variable, and check to see if another block has arrived before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while (latest_block <= my_last_block)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

This will cause the worker to wait until the main thread has incremented `latest_block` to be greater than `my_last_block` (the last block that was processed by this worker).

---

Your example test code has the same problem - sooner or later the main thread will call `pthread_cond_broadcast()` when a child thread is locking or unlocking the mutex, or inside the `printf()` call.

A version of your example code, updated to use the fix I mentioned, does not show this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define     SHM_KEY             9753
#define     NumOfChildProc      20

int Packets_Tx = 0, Packets_Rx = 0;

struct {
    pthread_cond_t     PTCond;
    pthread_mutex_t    PTMutex;
    int last_packet;
} *shared_data;

void ChildProc(void)
{
    int my_last_packet = 0;
    /* Create the shared memory with same key as SHM_KEY
     * Declare the condition and mutex and assign them the shared memory
       address */

     while(1)
     {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->PTMutex);
         while (shared_data->last_packet <= my_last_packet)
             pthread_cond_wait(&shared_data->PTCond, &shared_data->PTMutex);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->PTMutex);

         printf("From CP [%d]: Packets Received = %d\n",getpid(), Packets_Rx++);
         my_last_packet++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int     shmid, i;
    pid_t   l_pid;

    pthread_condattr_t  condattr;
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;

    shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof *shared_data, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if(shmid < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget");
    }

    shared_data = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if(shared_data == (void *) -1)
    {
        perror("shmat");
    }

    pthread_condattr_init(&condattr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_cond_init(&shared_data->PTCond, &condattr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&condattr);

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared_data->PTMutex, &mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexattr);

    shared_data->last_packet = 0;

    for(i=0; i<NumOfChildProc; i++)
    {
         l_pid = fork();
         if(l_pid == 0)
              ChildProc();
    }
    sleep(1);

    while(1)
    {
        /* Send pthread broadcast and increment the packets count */
        printf("From Main Process : Packets Sent = %d\n", Packets_Tx++);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->PTMutex);
        shared_data->last_packet++;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&shared_data->PTCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->PTMutex);
        usleep(30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankscaf and  @John Bollinger for your comments. I did consider the possibility that the child process was busy doing something else when pthread_cond_broadcast was sent. To check this I created a test program (added in the original question above). The producer is sending pthread broadcast every 1 ms and consumer is doing nothing but waiting on pthread_cond wait. When I executed this I observed the same  thing i.e. the consumer's packet count began lagging the producer's packet count after a while.

Comment: @Adhi: Your test program has exactly the same problem - sooner or later the main program is going to call `pthread_cond_broadcast()` at a moment when the child process is locking or unlocking the mutex or executing in `printf()`.  This is simply not the correct way to use a condition variable.

Comment: I have updated my question with a version of your example code with my suggested fix applied.